# Geonodes: How to raycast from another position?

Tags: geometry-nodes, shrinkwrap

How can I raycast from a different position? What I am trying to do is shrinkwrap a cube around a sphere using the raycast node whenever the sphere is outside the cube's boundaries. You can see in the image how it works[image: Cube Raycasting onto sphere.]

Problem with my geonodes setup is that the cube isn't shrinkwrapping around the sphere, just projecting the vertex onto the backside of the sphere. How can I make it shrinkwrap around the sphere? I tried using the positions of other objects but that didn't work.

Any ideas?

[Blend File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1e70s5Amreb4ylLhmKYOy4wYZXEF3ETfN/view?usp=share_link)

Comment: "around the sphere" will not work as long as the cube isn't placed around the sphere - because the _Raycast_ node does what the name suggests, it casts rays. Meaning it's projecting straight lines from one geometry to the other. There is no way it is gonna bend around the sphere and project anything on the opposite side...

Comment: Is there a workaround for this? Like using another objects raycast to say where to raycast to? Or another method? Thank you